# What did I do to offend the Python interpreter?

Tags: python, syntax-error

When I run the following code:

```
# This program calculates gross pay.
def main():

    # Get the number of hours worked.
    hours = int(input('How many hours did you work? '))

    # Get the hourly pay rate.
    pay_rate = float(input('Enter your hourly pay rate: '))

    # Calculate the gross pay.
    gross_pay = hours * pay_rate

    # Display the gross pay.
    print('Gross pay: $', format(gross_pay, ',.2f), sep=''')

# Call the main function.
main()
```

I get an error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax.
```

The last main is highlighted in red. What has gone wrong?

Comment: Please always post the full stack trace when asking a question about python.

Comment: I assume this is Python 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 types of string literals in python:

- `"a string"` or `'a string'` -- denotes a single-line string.
- `"""a string"""` or `'''a string'''` -- denotes a multiline string.

What you've done is (1) fail to close the string `,.2f`, and (2) inadvertently opened a (triple-quoted) multiline string literal:

```
print('Gross pay: $', format(gross_pay, ',.2f), sep=''')
                  missing a close quote here ^      ^^^ Opened a string literal
```

The interpreter assumes that everything after it is part of that string literal. When it can't find the closing parentheses (because you never closed the string literal), then it complains.

There are a two ways of fixing this:

1. Escape the middle quote: `sep='\'')`. This will prevent python from interpreting it as a multiline literal.
2. Use double quotes: `sep="'")`

Answer (score 4):

```
print('Gross pay: $', format(gross_pay, ',.2f), sep=''')
```

You failed to terminate a string. I guess you meant:

```
print('Gross pay: $', format(gross_pay, ',.2f'), sep='\'')
```

Or perhaps

```
print('Gross pay: $', format(gross_pay, ',.2f'), sep="'")
```

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a single quote on your `print('Gross pay: $', format(gross_pay, ',.2f), sep=''')` line, not to mention `sep='''` won't work. You've essentially done this:

```
print(
    "Gross pay: $",
    format(gross_pay,
    ",.2f), sep=''"
)
```

I'm assuming what you're trying to do is:

```
print("Gross pay: ${:,.2f}".format(gross_pay, sep="'"))
```